# Looking for references on JMS with ActiveMQ

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, jms, activemq-classic

Im doing a JMS project.
Can anybody point out a reference on running ActiveMQ (JMS) on two different PC using Eclipse on both PC?

Comment: I added the ActiveMQ tag so that community of users are more likely to see the question. You would probably get more responses if you voted and/or accepted the ones you do get, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this guide for an overview of ActiveMQ clustering...

http://activemq.apache.org/clustering.html